# display page1 until page2 dom is completly created

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

## I have two pages page1, page2.

page2 has large amount of data so it is take too long time for loading. mow i want to display page 1 until the page 2 is completely loaded. 
is it possible? if yes then please tell me how?

Comment: Maybe make a fullscreendiv in foreground with your page1 content and let it dissappear in on ready event!?

Comment: but i didn't want to display any other thing before the page 2 is completely loaded. my page 1 is using some api services so when someone click on search it opens a popup with a progress bar. it returns some data those data are posted to another page (page 2) this page is again call the api services and collect the data and display the result that's why it takes time to load. so i want to display page 1 until the page 2 is completely loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Don't load huge amount of data at a time

1.try to use jquery ajax

2.Bind images properly 
 You can not show two different

You can use a display none on the body and then bind an event listener for pageinit on your first page.

Example:

HTML:

```
<body style="display:none">
<div id="#start" data-role="page"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$("#start").one("pageinit",function(){
    $("body").show();
});
```

***[updated]***

See you can not archive this by **two pages remember page is only one but logic is different** you have initially only one page so don't load a content until first content means ***page 1*** is loaded and then check that your content is loaded then load another data

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....
but i didn't want to display any other thing before the page 2 is completely loaded. my page 1 is using some api services so when someone click on search it opens a popup with a progress bar. it returns some data those data are posted to another page (page 2) this page is again call the api services and collect the data and display the result that's why it takes time to load. so i want to display page 1 until the page 2 is completely loaded.

Comment: @sourav check udpated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.ajax().done()` method to handle page2 activation and deactivation.

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/